# SharePoint Maintain Scroll Position

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have SharePoint 2013 web part and it has a lot of auto post pack drop down lists, i tried many methods of java script and code behind methods in vb.net and i couldn't get the solution keeping the position of any drop down list after post backing.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i have got it by the easiest way of using:

```
$('#s4-workspace').animate({scrollTop:x},'Way Of Scrolling');
```

Where `x` is in pixels and way of scrolling is fast or slow, so it will be something like:

```
$('#s4-workspace').animate({scrollTop:500},'slow');
```

Comment: Well done for bothering to come back and writing down the answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i wish it can help someone got the same issue.